# Can you collapse a Bootstrap Button Group?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a site that uses a Bootstrap button group for navigation. However, I would like to get it to collapse into the hamburger icon like a Navbar does. I've done some searching but haven't found anything to address it. Is it possible to collapse a button group or do I have to use a Navabar?

I tried to quickly style up a Navbar using buttons but it's not working out very well and I then found some posts that say not to use buttons in the Navbar.

Here is the basic layout of our button group.

```
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm btn-group-justified">
        <a href="@Url.Action("ScheduleDetails", "Home")" class="menu-item">Schedule</a>
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "LogOut")" class="menu-item">Log Out</a>
    </div>

.menu-item {
    .btn;
    .btn-sm;
    .btn-default;
    color: @header-text-color;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
HTML:
    <!-- Static navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> 
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
 .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus,
    .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover {
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
        border: none;
    }

    .navbar-toggle span.icon-bar {
        transition: all 0.15s;
    }

    .navbar-toggle span:nth-child(2) {
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        transform-origin: 10% 10%;
    }

    .navbar-toggle span:nth-child(3) {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    .navbar-toggle span:nth-child(4) {
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
        transform-origin: 10% 90%;
    }

    .navbar-toggle.collapsed span:nth-child(2),
    .navbar-toggle.collapsed span:nth-child(4) {
        transform: rotate(0);
    }

    .navbar-toggle.collapsed span:nth-child(3) {
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but when I give it a try it just shows as the hamburger icon on all screen sizes. I'm looking to display a button group on a Medium - Large screen then have it collapse when it's in a smaller size.